# Responsive javascript width of div in pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Specific I have a Joomla based cms using Yootheme Nano3 template with integrated responsive layout. The content below the blue header (see website) have 3 columns using % for all 3 in the css. [improvecycling.com](http://improvecycling.com/)

```
<div class="tm-main">
<aside class="tm-sidebar-a">
<aside class="tm-sidebar-b">
```

This brings the tm-main in top of the html code.

I want the tm-sidebar-a+b to be 190 px at all time and the tm-main to fix the with 100% minus 2x190 if both exist. Sounds simple but I have looked all places for a fix for this to come true.

Jquery would be prefered if its possible.

Comment: maybe but how? all 3 divs are percent 20/60/20% I dont know of any css 3 functions that can deal with other divs and act accordingly. Its easy for me to do the 2x190px but to fill out the gap of the rest I cant figure out

Comment: .tm-main { width:calc(100% - 380px); } -- Then set the asides to 190px width, and float them all.

Comment: hmm try that out. didnt know about that one. maybe I should erase the css expert thing in my profile ;o) ... be right back

Comment: Did just do this css. calc() functoin. Found out that gzip compression of js and css files doesnt go with this function... so I have turned it off.

Comment: Using Samsung tablet 10" Android ver 4.0.3 the wesbsite doesnt look like supposed to. does calc() not work with this standard browser? I did ad -webkit- -moz- and -o- for this to respond to different browsers.